# An Undisturbed Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *My prefix is gotten before the race starts. 
>  My suffix will enter without pausing parts. 
>  My infix will soften with heat, switching hearts. 
>  I am, altogether, a place to remain.*
>
> *My prefix, an asset but not as it starts. 
>  My suffix won't enterta'n mixed ret'na parts. 
>  My infix is crying, but back in my hearts. 
>  I am posted out, unlike quite a domain.*
>
> ***What am I?***

The answer has $10$ letters, and the title is also a clue.

Comment: You and those Triple M I stanzas. Lol

Comment: @PerpetualJ Hahaha, it makes it look neat :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Settlement

My prefix is gotten before the race starts.

> Set - "Ready, **Set**, Go"

My suffix will enter without pausing parts.

> Ent - Enter without 'er'.

My infix will soften with heat, switching hearts.

> Melt - It's backwards within the word.

I am, altogether, a place to remain.

> Settlement

My prefix, an asset but not as it starts.

> Set - Asset without 'as'

My suffix won't enterta'n mixed ret'na parts.

> Ent - enterta'n without ret'na

My infix is crying, but back in my hearts.

> Melt

I am posted out, unlike quite a domain.

> Settlement

Comment: Yes, you got it correct! Well done! No need to explain the title (I am sure you understand why I wrote it like that). Also, the part "**di**" is in **undisturbed** (and **di** means two, sometimes, referring to the two Riley verses) hahah. Great job! When would you like the tick? :P

Comment: Eh, I will give you the tick now. I have finished making Riley Riddles for a long while. Congratulations! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Comment: @user477343 Sorry, missed your earlier comment, thank you for the tick. Nice riddle!

Comment: Thank you! Since you are nearly on $30k$ rep, you are obviously experienced, especially with riddles. Thus I ask you, is there any advice you can give that would possibly improve my writing of riddles?